# before all" hook: Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves

Tags: mocha.js, detox

My package.json id define below and I am using e2e pattern and not define any test file. My test case come under e2e and contain test text so that mocha can read it

```
{
  "name": "appOfCard",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",

    "watch:test": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "clean-cache": "watchman watch-del-all",
    "svg-transform": "msvgc -f ./src/shared-ui/Icon/svg/$SVG.svg -o ./src/shared-ui/Icon/native/ --react-native",
    "#svg_cmd_example": "SVG=search yarn run svg-transform",
    "syncmessages": "node syncI18n.js",
    "postinstall": "npm run syncmessages",
    "rnd": "adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_MENU",
    "runios": "react-native run-ios --simulator='iPhone 7'",
    "runandroid": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && react-native run-android",
    "precommit": "lint-staged && npm run test && npm run syncmessages",
    "lint": "eslint src",
    "lint-fix": "eslint --fix src",
    "test": "mocha .\\e2e\\*test.js",
    "detox-server": "detox-server",
    "e2e": "mocha e2e --opts ./e2e/mocha.opts",
    "build": "xcodebuild -project NativeExample.xcodeproj -scheme NativeExample -derivedDataPath . -sdk iphonesimulator"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./src/assets/fonts"
    ]
  },
  "moduleRoots": [
    "./src/"
  ],
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.js": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "base-64": "^0.1.0",
    "creditcardutils": "^1.0.0",
    "email-validator": "^1.1.1",
    "gem": "^2.4.2",
    "geolib": "^2.0.24",
    "husky": "^0.14.3",
    "i18n-iso-countries": "^3.3.0",
    "i18n-js": "^3.0.1",
    "is-email": "^1.0.0",
    "jsbarcode": "^3.8.0",
    "lint-staged": "^7.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "lodash.groupby": "^4.6.0",
    "moment": "^2.19.1",
    "normalizr": "^3.2.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.51.0",
    "react-native-acc": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-acc-gcm": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-appsflyer": "1.1.12",
    "react-native-barcode-builder": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-camera": "https://github.com/PierreYvesParis/react-native-camera.git#stable",
    "react-native-communications": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-device-brightness": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^0.17.4",
    "react-native-extended-stylesheet": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-firebase": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.12.1",
    "react-native-i18n": "^2.0.6",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.26.7",
    "react-native-image-progress": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-interactable": "^0.1.3",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "~0.4.3",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-maps": "~0.20.0",
    "react-native-material-textfield": "https://github.com/antoinegrelard/react-native-material-textfield.git#master",
    "react-native-modal": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-open-maps": "^0.1.1",
    "react-native-open-settings": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-photo-view": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-section-list-get-item-layout": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-shadow": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-shadow-view": "^0.0.1",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^5.5.1",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.13",
    "react-native-text-input-reset": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-version-check": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-video": "^2.0.0",
    "react-navigation": "~1.1.2",
    "react-navigation-redux-helpers": "~1.0.1",
    "react-navigation-slide-from-right-transition": "^1.0.4",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-string-replace": "^0.4.1",
    "recompose": "^0.25.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-persist": "^4.10.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "reselect": "^3.0.1",
    "shortid": "^2.2.8",
    "sync-spreadsheet": "^1.0.7",
    "vanilla-masker": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "8.2.1",
    "babel-jest": "21.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "2.7.1",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "3.0.2",
    "detox": "^7.3.7",
    "eslint": "4.16.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "15.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "2.9.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-babel-module": "3.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "2.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.5.1",
    "jest": "21.0.2",
    "mocha": "^5.1.1",
    "msvgc": "^0.1.1",
    "prettier": "1.10.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.11.0"


},
   "detox": {
    "specs": "e2e",
     "configurations": {
       "ios.sim.debug": {
         "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/debug-iphonesimulator/appOfCard.app",
       "build": "xcodebuild -project ios/appOfCard.xcodeproj -scheme appOfCard -configuration debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
         "type": "ios.simulator",
         "name": "iPhone 8 Plus"

       }
     }
   }
}
```

My init.js file code

```
const detox = require('detox');
const config = require('../package.json').detox;
-require('babel-polyfill');
before(async () => {
  await detox.init(config);
});

after(async () => {
  await detox.cleanup();
});
```